# How to add functionality of speed increase/decrease in Flick Video Player Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

I am using Flick Video Player in Flutter. I want to add speed functionality on the screen of video just like other buttons like volume. How to do this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use this `setPlaybackSpeed(value)` from **FlickManager** like this `flickManager.flickControlManager?.setPlaybackSpeed(speed);`

here is a simple example of how you can use the speed control with [flick_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flick_video_player)
I added you two classes one for normal popup menu button and another one like slider using [syncfusion_flutter_sliders](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders)

> home_screen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
      videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse('https://github.com/GeekyAnts/flick-video-player-demo-videos/blob/master/example/9th_may_compressed.mp4?raw=true'),
      ),
    );
  }




  @override
  void dispose() {
    flickManager.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FlickVideoPlayerWidget(flickManager: flickManager,),
    );
  }

}
```

> flick_video_speed_control_widget.dart

```
class FlickVideoSpeedControlWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlickManager flickManager;

  const FlickVideoSpeedControlWidget({super.key, required this.flickManager});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<double>(
      initialValue: flickManager.flickVideoManager?.videoPlayerValue?.playbackSpeed ?? 1.0,
      onSelected: (speed) {
        flickManager.flickControlManager?.setPlaybackSpeed(speed);
      },
      itemBuilder: (context) => [
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 0.5,
          child: Text("0.5x"),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1.0,
          child: Text("1x"),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1.5,
          child: Text("1.5x"),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 2.0,
          child: Text("2x"),
        ),
      ],
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Icon(Icons.speed,size: 35,color: Colors.red,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> flick_video_speed_control_slider_widget.dart

```
class FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final FlickManager flickManager;

  const FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidget(
      {super.key, required this.flickManager});

  @override
  _FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidgetState createState() =>
      _FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidgetState();
}

class _FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidgetState
    extends State<FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidget> {
  double _sliderValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfSlider(
      min: 0.0,
      max: 2.0,
      value: widget.flickManager.flickVideoManager?.videoPlayerValue
              ?.playbackSpeed ??
          1.0,
      interval: 0.5,
      showTicks: true,
      showLabels: true,
      enableTooltip: true,
      minorTicksPerInterval: 0,
      // Adjust this for more minor ticks between intervals
      onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
        widget.flickManager.flickControlManager?.setPlaybackSpeed(newValue);
        setState(() {
          _sliderValue = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> flick_video_player_widget.dart

```
  class FlickVideoPlayerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlickManager flickManager;

  const FlickVideoPlayerWidget({super.key, required this.flickManager});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        /// here is the speed control

        FlickVideoSpeedControlSliderWidget(flickManager: flickManager),
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              FlickVideoPlayer(
                flickManager: flickManager,
                flickVideoWithControls: const FlickVideoWithControls(
                  controls: FlickPortraitControls(),
                ),
                flickVideoWithControlsFullscreen:  FlickVideoWithControls(
                  videoFit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  controls: Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        FlickVideoSpeedControlWidget(flickManager: flickManager),

                        Align(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                          child: const FlickLandscapeControls(
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  playerLoadingFallback: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  iconThemeData: IconThemeData(size: 30, color: Colors.white),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),

              Align(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                  child: FlickVideoSpeedControlWidget(flickManager: flickManager)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I want to have the button for setting speed on the video player just like the mute button is there. I have edited my question and have added an image for your reference. See top right corner.

Comment: @Adnan just wrap the video player within a stack i will update flick_video_player_widget.dart

Comment: Yeah it worked but the speed icon is not visible when we enter the full screen mode. What to do now?

Comment: And speed button should disappear as on tap of screen

Comment: you can update the controls inside flickVideoWithControlsFullscreen property. check the code again i already updated

Comment: Yeah button is there in full screen mode but pop up in not working on tap